# Can "as much as..." be used instead of "no matter how much..."?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, phrase-usage

For example, is it correct to use

> As much as they tighten the shackles, we will never surrender.

instead of

> No matter how much they tighten the shackles, we will never surrender.

and if it is not correct, is there another alternative to “No matter how much…” ?

Comment: The second example is appropriate.  "As much as" has a different meaning.  It can mean "even though" or "almost", or describe things being equal,  depending on usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[As much as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20much%20as)** is primarily used to say that two things are equal in amount or degree

> *He likes hockey as much as he likes basketball.*

It has a secondary meaning as  ***even though*** :  ***despite the fact that.***

> *As much as I respect him, I still have to disagree with him on this
>   point.*

In this sense the sentence ***As much as they tighten...*** can be rephrase as ***Even though*** (*Despite the fact that*) ***they tighten the shackles, we will never surrender.***

But it seems to me still the most appropriate sentence is ***No matter how much they tighten the shackles, we will never surrender.***